# 5" DSI LCD display turns black after startup Raspbian w/out GUI

Tags: display

I recently got a [Waveshare 5" touchscreen LCD display](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B091FYFNV8/?coliid=I150R6BO13R5FC&colid=1RNGLD0UI8IP2&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it&th=1) for my Raspberry Pi 4B.
I attached the Pi to the back of the display and connected it.
When I started up my Pi, it first gave me the impression it just works (3 raspberries appeared, followed by the usual startup text running on the screen). However, before it prompted me to enter my username, the screen turned black.

Now I wondered whether it is an issue of the screen format (i.e., the display is still working but shows only a part of the image and it just so happened the text is "outside" the displayed area)
or the display does not work without the GUI. Or are there problems related to the touch function and the circumstance, that I removed the GUI? (I don't need touch on my Pi, I just wanted it to have a cheap screen.)

I connected a second screen via HDMI to see what happens.
During startup, it `Started Bluetooth`, then `Started Hostname Service`. After that, the new screen just turned black.
On my second screen, it continued with `Started dhcpcd on all interfaces`.

Maybe someone has an idea what could have happened here and whether it is possible in the first place, to use the display with the given configuration.

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: Linux 5.10.63-v8+
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the required configuration settings in `boot/config.txt`? For many displays, you need to explicitly specify the size and resolution of the display for it to work properly.

Comment: On https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_DSI_LCD?Amazon they write: "If you are using the Buster branch system, the DSI LCD can work with Raspberry Pi directly after connecting and powering on". When I type ```lsb_release -a``` it says ```buster```. So I assume I don't have to change ```/boot/config.txt```(?) They say it's Plug&play...

Comment: [This documentation](https://www.joy-it.net/files/files/Produkte/RB-LCD-5/RB-LCD5-Manual-04.09.20.pdf) about a probably (?) very similar display says something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now. The problem was, that the documentation is a bit misleading. They state that *"If you are using the Buster branch system, the DSI LCD can work with Raspberry Pi directly after connecting and powering on. But if you are using the Bullseye branch system, you need to modify the config.txt as below:"*

I **am** using the Buster branch system. Regardless, I had to edit config.txt. I did not expect I had to, since the first line to comment out was not even in my config.txt.

Changing the lines "as if I was using Bullseye", I made it work.

I just had to add the following lines:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
start_x=1
```

and comment out

```
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```